# Is there a way to filter part of the string from an array of object with a given array of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Inside each object I have to know if this peace of string exists or not. I have this numbs array that is generated automatically, so my function can only bring in customers array the separated numbers (and not **each number with the respective name** as it should) if exists inside numbs.

```
numbs = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
customers = [{name: "Pedro", number: "9"}, {name: "Ivo", number: "6,4,7,3"}];

function customerNames (arr) { 
    return numbs.filter(function(index) {
        return arr.some(function(numberCompared) {
            return numberCompared.number.includes(index)
        })
    });
}

console.log(customerNames(customers));
```

By filtering the customer array I create a new one without the names, and I can't figure out how to check if inside customer array includes for example the value "6", every function I found on internet similar to my problem is to compare two array of objects sorted in different ways.

```js
    numbs = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
    customers = [{name: "Pedro", number: "9"}, {name: "Ivo", number: "6,4,7,3"}];

    function customerNames (arr) { 
        return numbs.filter(function(index) {
            return arr.some(function(numberCompared) {
                return numberCompared.number.includes(index)
            })
        });
    }
    
console.log("Customers:", JSON.stringify(customerNames(customers)));
```

Comment: what output do you expect?, I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: Im confused, what's your final goal? is it to filter the customers array by the number field in each object, based on the values in the numbs field? Or are you trying to filter the customers array by the values of the objects inside it. so like filter number == 9 would return {name: "Pedro", number: "9"}

Comment: @RahulKumar I expect to receive something like customerNames = [{name: "Ivo", number: "3"}, {name: "Ivo", number: "4"}, {name: "Ivo", number: "6"}, {name: "Ivo", number: "7"}, {name: "Pedro", number: "9"} ];

Comment: @cigolon The first one, but sincerely I rathered give this doubt so the two solutions you drawed would satisfy. But now you asked I see how lacking in objectiveness is not correct when asking questions.

Comment: @pebueno added the answer which returns the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.reduce()` method to return final customer list and inside the method check if numbers `includes` the customer number.

```js
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
customers = [{ name: "Pedro", number: "9" },
{ name: "Ivo", number: "6,4,7,3" }];

function customerNames(customers, numbers) {
  return customers.reduce((list, customer) => {
    const cNums = customer.number.split(",").map(num => `${num}`)
    for (num of cNums) {
      if (numbers.includes(num)) {
        const customerObj = {
          name: customer.name,
          number: num
        }
        list.push(customerObj);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }, []);
}

console.log("Customers: ", (customerNames(customers, numbers)));
```